# Setting Unity SpriteRenderer color makes sprite invisible/dissapear

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class ColorSwap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color color;

    void Start(){
        this.getComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = color;
    }
}
```

I've set the color in the inspector. I can see it set.

I tried using 
    this.getComponent().color = color;

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ironically, the problem was that the "color" struct was auto initialized to Color(0,0,0,0);

When changing the color in the color picker, the Hue changes, but not the Alpha.

So, even though I thought I set it to (1.0, 0, 0), it was actually set to (1.0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: A tip for using `Color`: Each parameter should be in the range `0..1`, not `0..255`. For examples, see http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html -- the Yellow variable is a good example.

Comment: If you want 0..255 values, then use Color32 instead of Color.

Comment: I think the actual values were irrelevant to the answer, but thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the question. :D